# Calibrating axis joystick problem

Tags: raspbian, joystick

I acquired this interface with buttons for 2 players (http://www.arcadeoutlet.es/es/interfaces-jamma/27-jamma-to-usb-2p.html)

I follow this steps to connect my joysticks with raspberry pi (http:// angelverde.info/configuracion-avanzada-instalando-joystick-gamepad-karmic-koala/)

I have done all the steps to the calibration of dipositive. I recognized it as Bus 001 Device 009: ID 16c0: 05e1 VOTI CDC-ACM class devices (modems)

The fact is that to calibrate eg axis 0, my device only returns 1 when I move it to the right and 0 in the center and left. In the tutorial says it should return 0, 128 and 255. The axis 1 returns 1 when I move it down and 0 in all other cases.

This results in the mame me, I just work right, bottom and buttons. Left and above does not work.

In windows all joysticks and buttons works fine.

I have run jstest / dev/input/js0 me and detects all buttons and right / bottom of the two joysticks.

js call only detect 4 axis. But i have 2 joysticks:

```
Joystick has 4 axes and 22 buttons.
Correction for axis 0 is broken line, precision is 0.
Coeficients are: 0, 0, 536870912, 536870912
Correction for axis 1 is broken line, precision is 0.
Coeficients are: 0, 0, 536870912, 536870912
Correction for axis 2 is broken line, precision is 0.
Coeficients are: 0, 0, 536870912, 536870912
Correction for axis 3 is broken line, precision is 0.
Coeficients are: 0, 0, 536870912, 536870912
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/orayC.jpg

Plug in/out the joystick retrieve this lines in syslog

```
Jan 31 01:10:54 raspberrypi kernel: [   48.458230] usb 1-1.3: USB disconnect, device number 5
Jan 31 01:10:57 raspberrypi kernel: [   51.253379] usb 1-1.3: new low-speed USB device number 6 using dwc_otg
Jan 31 01:10:57 raspberrypi kernel: [   51.360054] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=16c0, idProduct=05e1
Jan 31 01:10:57 raspberrypi kernel: [   51.360087] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Jan 31 01:10:57 raspberrypi kernel: [   51.360104] usb 1-1.3: Product: THT Arcade console 2P USB Player
Jan 31 01:10:57 raspberrypi kernel: [   51.360119] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: THT
Jan 31 01:10:57 raspberrypi kernel: [   51.378515] input: THT THT Arcade console 2P USB Player as /devices/platform/bcm2708_usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/input/input3
Jan 31 01:10:57 raspberrypi kernel: [   51.380388] hid-generic 0003:16C0:05E1.0004: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.01 Joystick [THT THT Arcade console 2P USB Player] on usb-bcm2708_usb-1.3/input0
```

Comment: Sorry, I can't figure much of the spanish links. Nevertheless, I never heard of a joystick being enumerated as a modem. Please run `tail -f /var/log/syslog` in a terminal, plug the device in, and post whatever appear then. Additionnally your 2nd link is broken due to a space after http:// and I can't make an edit of less than 6 characters.

Comment: The 2nd link is a tutorial where they learn to calibrate joystick with jscal. I refresh my question with tail -f /var/log/syslog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution

It's need to recompile raspbian's kernel with a drivers modified

http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=78&t=36564&start=25

Que bueno soy, y que culito tengo